# How to pass the obfuscated program's trace protocol through compiler-optimizer?

Tags: gdb, compiler-optimization, deobfuscation

With help of GDB-script:

```
file ./program
b *0x12345
run
while 1
x/i $pc
ni
end
quit
```

I got a trace protocol of obfuscated program:

```
        ...

0x484e0:    bx  lr
?? ()
0x43d88:    b   0x43db8
?? ()
0x43db8:    ldr r3, [r11, #-16]
?? ()
0x43dbc:    mov r0, r3
?? ()
0x43dc0:    sub sp, r11, #12
?? ()
0x43dc4:    pop {r4, r5, r11, pc}
?? ()
0x3fb94:    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
?? ()
0x3fb98:    mov r0, r3
?? ()
0x3fb9c:    sub sp, r11, #4
?? ()
0x3fba0:    pop {r11, pc}
?? ()
0x3da68:    ldr r3, [r11, #-8]

        ...
```

Kris Kaspersky writes, that it is good idea to pass the tracer's protocol through compiler-optimizer for better understanding of this program. But I haven't any idea what compilers and in what way should I use.

P.S. What should I do to get rid of unnecessary lines: "?? ()" ? And what should I do to redirect GDB's out to file?

**Edited:**

Book: Kris Kaspersky "Искусство дизассемблирования", book in Russian (translation - "Art of disassembling"). Chapter №39, Page 822 (under the listing). I haven't any idea is English analogue exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Kris Kaspersky writes, that it is good idea to pass the tracer's protocol through compiler-optimizer for better understanding of this program. But I haven't any idea what compilers and in what way should I use.

I know what compilers are, but still have no idea what you are talking about. If you provide a link to the document you are reading, you might get better answers.

> What should I do to get rid of unnecessary lines: "?? ()" ?

Use `grep` to filter them out, e.g.

```
grep -v '\?' trace.txt > clean-trace.txt
```

or

```
grep '^0x' trace.txt > clean-trace.txt
```

> And what should I do to redirect GDB's out to file?

```
(gdb) set logging on  # output will now be copied to gdb.txt
```

Comment: Kris Kaspersky "Искусство дизассемблирования", book in Russian (translation - "Art of disassembling"). Chapter №39, Page 822 (under the listing). I haven't any idea is English analogue exist.